# Jetpack compose data store keeps recomposing screen

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I'm migrating from Shared preference to data store using jetpack compose. everything works fine (data is saved and can be retreated successfully). However, whenever a Data is retrieved, the composable keeps on recomposing endlessly. I'm using MVVM architecture and below is how I have implemented data store.

**Below is declared in my AppModule.kt**

*App module in SingletonComponent*

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideUserPreferenceRepository(@ApplicationContext context: Context):
        UserPreferencesRepository = UserPreferencesRepositoryImpl(context)
```

**Then here's my ViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class StoredUserViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val _getUserDataUseCase: GetUserDataUseCase
): ViewModel() {

private val _state = mutableStateOf(UserState())
val state: State<UserState> = _state

fun getUser(){
    _getUserDataUseCase().onEach { result ->
        val name = result.name
        val token = result.api_token
        _state.value = UserState(user = UserPreferences(name, agentCode, token, balance))
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
 }}
```

**Finally, Here's my Repository Implementation:**

```
class UserPreferencesRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val context: Context
): UserPreferencesRepository {

private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = "user_preferences")
}
private object Keys {
    val fullName = stringPreferencesKey("full_name")
    val api_token = stringPreferencesKey("api_token")
}

private inline val Preferences.fullName get() = this[Keys.fullName] ?: ""
private inline val Preferences.apiToken get() = this[Keys.api_token] ?: ""

override val userPreferences: Flow<UserPreferences> = context.dataStore.data.catch{
//        throws an IOException when an error is encountered when reading data
    if (it is IOException) {
        emit(emptyPreferences())
    } else {
        throw it
    }
}.map { preferences ->
    UserPreferences(name = preferences.fullName, api_token = preferences.apiToken)
}.distinctUntilChanged()
```

I don't know what causes the composable to recompose. Below Is the composable:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
navController: NavController,
userViewModel: StoredUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

Log.v("LOGIN_SCREEN", "CALLED!")
userViewModel.getUser()
}
```

If anyone can tell me where I've done wrong please enlighten me. I have tried to change the implementation in AppModule for UserPreferencesRepository but no luck.

**Below is UseState.kt which is just a data class**

```
data class UserState(
val user: UserPreferences? = null
)
```

**Below is UserPreferences.kt**

```
data class UserPreferences(val name: String, val api_token: String)
```

Comment: you never posted `UserState` so we can't know

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have added the codes for UserState which is just a data class

Comment: ok now we need `UserPreferences` :D

Comment: It is also a data class, I've edited the question and included it. @EpicPandaForce

Comment: There goes my guess, maybe use `stateIn` for your flow

Comment: @EpicPandaForce let me try that one. Thanks, will get back with an feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced such problem. The solution was became to navigate with LauchedEffect in composable.

before:

```
if (hasFlight) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.StartMovingScreen.route)
}
```

after:

```
if (hasFlight) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.StartMovingScreen.route)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour: you're calling `getUser` on each recomposition.

`@Composable` function is a view builder, and should be side-effects free.

Instead you can use special side effect function, like `LaunchedEffect`, which will launch job only once, until it's removed from view tree or `key` argument is changed:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    userViewModel.getUser()
}
```

But this also will be re-called in case of configuration change, e.g. screen rotation. To prevent this case, you have two options:

1. Call `getUser` inside view model `init`: in this case it's guarantied that it's called only once.
2. Create some flag inside view model to prevent redundant request.

More info about Compose side effects in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Comment: , I think there’s a little small thing i failed to mention. The composable gets recalled only when i navigate to another composable. But initially i can call getUser and it will not recompose in a loop at all. But once I navigate to another composable that is when it keeps on recomposing in loop even when i pop the stack to remove it from stack before navigating. Initially i was calling getUser in viewModel init but that did not solve the problem. Maybe the Flag idea must help. Let me put a flag and see. Thanks mate

Comment: @timtimer compose navigation recomposing views multiple times during navigation transition, this is expected behaviour. `LaunchedEffect` should be used to prevent multiple calls in this case.

Comment: if you don't need a coroutine, you can also use `DisposableEffect(Unit) {` with an empty `onDispose {` block

Comment: @PhilipDukhov LaunchedEffect did not work. I get the same result.